# Why linear regression feature coefficients become super large?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, feature-selection, linear-regression, features

### Introduction

I've implemented linear regression using `sklearn` and after all calculations I've got results like this:

```
Feature: 0, coef: -9985335237.46533
Feature: 1, coef: 417387013140.39661
Feature: 2, coef: -2.85809
Feature: 3, coef: 1.50522
Feature: 4, coef: -1.07076
```

---

### Data

My data is based on user visits in gym. All data normalized `0 <= x <= 1`. Data set has 10k observations.

**X:**

- feature_0: gym's rating
- feature_1: gym's review(rating) count
- feature_2: gym's one visit price
- feature_3: gym's unlimited subscription price
- feature_4: distance to gym from user's home | calculated `min(x / 30, 1.0)`, because mean is 15.17

**Y:** user's visit count to that gym

[Data sample](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/Sh7JjKpkwQ/)

---

### Code

```
from sklearn.datasets import make_regression
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from matplotlib import pyplot
from numpy import loadtxt

# define dataset
x = loadtxt('formatted_data_x.txt')
y = loadtxt('formatted_data_y.txt')
# define the model
model = LinearRegression()
# fit the model
model.fit(x, y)
# get importance
importance = model.coef_
# summarize feature importance
for i,v in enumerate(importance):
    print('Feature: %0d, coef: %.5f' % (i,v))
```

---

### Question

Why linear regression feature coefficients become super large? Is it okay?

```
Feature: 0, coef: -9985335237.46533
Feature: 1, coef: 417387013140.39661
...
```

---

**P.S:** I'm new to this "part" of **StackExchange** and **ML\DS** at all, so please if I do something wrong or I have to provide more information, let me know! Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: How big is your dataset?

Comment: @nwaldo 10k observations

Comment: Have you normalized the data before performing regression.

Comment: @BenReiniger I’ve just used cross validation dividing to 5 parts and it shows -0.1, seems very bad.

Comment: @ShubhamPanchal yes

Comment: Please add you full code, I can't see Normalization part. What is the extra point that you have mentioned for featire_4. Is your train, test score ok? Any Outliers, then do Standardization not Normalization.

Comment: @RoshanJha my normalization is just dividing each value by maximum in that feature values. Should I user some other normalization? My extra about 4th feature is that I guess 30km as the maximum, because I have some trash in user location.

Comment: What is your aim? Prediction? When you do nothing to the data (no normalisation etc), linear regression would read like: "If gym rating goes up by one unit, user's visit change by "Feature: 0, coef" units. Not knowing how your data looks like, it is impossible to say if you might have a problem here. You can do any linear transformation to the data without corrupting results. However, the interpretation of coefs changes in this case. If you have super small unit changes, super large coefs would be a "normal" result.

Comment: @Peter thanks for your response, if I share some data bunch of data, can u give me some advices?

Comment: A phenomenon called "(multi-)collinearity".

Comment: @MichaelM you were right, I've plot my data and they are almost the same, when I drop some of them, it works okay! Thanks!

Comment: Two of your features has a consistently small value. 
These features might have some outliers. You should standardize instead of Normalize.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Large coefficients in linear regression are not necessarily a problem. They can be large becuase some variable was rescaled. You mentionned that you do some rescaling, but provide no details. Therefore it is not possible to tell what exactly is going on.

Here is a (general) example that explains how coefficients can get "large" (in `R`). Assume we want to model "visits" ($y$) contingent on "rating" ($x$):

```
# Data
df = data.frame(c(1,3,5,3,7,5,8,9,7,10),c(34,54,31,45,65,78,56,87,69,134))
colnames(df)<-c("rating","visits")

# Regression 1
reg1 = lm(visits~rating,data=df)
summary(reg1)
```

The regression results are:

```
Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)  
(Intercept)   19.452     15.273   1.274   0.2385  
rating         7.905      2.379   3.322   0.0105 *
```

This tells us, that `visits` increase by about 7.9 when `rating` increases by one unit. This is basically a linear function with intercept 19.45 and slope 7.9. Since our model is 
$$ y = \beta_0 + \beta_1 x + u ,$$
the corresponding (estimated) linear function would look like:
$$f(x) = 19.45 + 7.9 x .$$

We can predict and plot our model. The results are just as expected, a positive linear function.

```
# Predict and plot
pred1 = predict(reg1,newdata=df)
plot(df$rating,df$visits,xlab="Rating",ylab="Visits")
lines(df$rating,pred1)
```

[image]

Now comes the interesting part: I do a linear transformation on $x$. Namely, I divide $x$ by some "large" number and I run the same regression as before:

```
# Transform x
large_integer = 10000000
df$rating2 = df$rating/large_integer
df

   rating visits rating2
1       1     34   1e-07
2       3     54   3e-07
3       5     31   5e-07
4       3     45   3e-07
5       7     65   7e-07
6       5     78   5e-07
7       8     56   8e-07
8       9     87   9e-07
9       7     69   7e-07
10     10    134   1e-06

# Regression 2 (with transformed x)
reg2 = lm(visits~rating2,data=df)
summary(reg2)
```

The results are:

```
Coefficients:
             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)  
(Intercept) 1.945e+01  1.527e+01   1.274   0.2385  
rating2     7.905e+07  2.379e+07   3.322   0.0105 *
```

As you see, the coefficient for `rating` is rather large now. However, when I predict and plot, I get basically the same results as before. The only thing that has changed is the "scale" of $x$ (the way $x$ is expressed).

[image]

Let's compare the coefficient for `rating` in both regressions.

In the first case it was:

```
# Relevant coefficient "rating" from reg1 (the "small" one)
reg1$coefficients[2]

  rating 
7.904762
```

In the second case it was:

```
# Relevant coefficient "rating2" from reg2 (the "large" one)
reg2$coefficients[2]

 rating2 
79047619
```

However, when I divide the coefficient `rating2` by the same "large" number as I did to "rescale" the data, I get:

```
# "Rescale" large coefficient
reg2$coefficients[2]/large_integer

 rating2 
7.904762
```

As you can see, the "rescaled" coefficient `rating2` is exactly the same as the original coefficient for `rating`.

**What can you do to check your regression:**

- Run the regression without any rescaling and see if the results make sense
- Make a prediction from the regression
- Rescale your data (i.e. "standardise"), which should contribute to get better predictions because data are less "wonky" in this case. However, coefficients have no natural interpretation any more
- Compare standardised data to non-standardised to see how your data changed. Based on the discussion above, you should get a good idea if very small or large coefficients can make sense after standardisation
- Make a prediction, compare to the prediction from above

Comment: Peter, thanks for ur answer! Let me try :) then I will come with some feedback

Comment: Thanks for your answer, now I have very bad training score(-0.10), can you please share some links on how to improve my prediction?

Comment: what did you do exactly to end up with this score, and what kind of score is it? R2?